# Variable Expression: Count all records where condition >0 is met

Tags: jasper-reports, ireport

I created a variable to keep a count of all machinery_part_id in a location for my report.  This works fine, now I want to add a filter where the machinery_part_id is only counted if they have a quantity > 0.

**This is what I had to start with:**

Variable Name: PART_COUNT

Variable Class Type: Java.lang.Integer

Calculation Type: Count

Reset Type: Group

Reset Group: LOCATION_ID

Increment Type: None

Variable Expression: $F{MACHINERY_PART_ID}

**A field in my report was set up as follows:**

Text Field Expression Class: Java.lang.Integer

Evaluation Time: Group

Evaluation Group: LOCATION_ID

Text Field Expression: $V{PART_COUNT}

The new condition is count(machinery_part_id) group by location_id having quantity >0

`$F{MACHINERY_PART_ID}` and `$F{QUANTITY_SENT}` are both `java.lang.double` fields, I tried entering the following in the Variable Expression:

```
New Double($F{QUANTITY_SENT} > 0.00 ?  $F{QUANTITY_SENT}.doubleValue() : 0d)
```

**But it errors out with:**

```
Syntax error, insert ";" to complete BlockStatements
```

I'm using iReport 3.0.0

Please help,
Thanks!

Comment: Maybe I'm interpreting this incorrectly, but it looks like your variable and field are integers, and your variable expression "New Double($F{QUANTITY_SENT...) is looking to create a double? And is your expression language set to Java or Groovy?

Comment: The Expression language is Java.

Comment: I tried changing the Variable Expression to: '($F{QUANTITY_SENT} > 0.00 ?  $F{QUANTITY_SENT} : 0d)' and it errors out with  'The operator > is undefined for the argument type(s) Double, double'

Comment: I switched the Variable Class Type and the Text Field Expression Class to java.lang.double and tried `New Double($F{QUANTITY_SENT}.doubleValue() > 0.00 ?  $F{QUANTITY_SENT}.doubleValue() : 0d)` It doesnt error out anymore but its only excluding records where $F{QUANTITY_SENT} is null.  Records with $F{QUANTITY_SENT}=0.00 are still being counted.

Answer (score 1):

I figured it out:

**VARIABLE**

Variable Name: PART_COUNT

Variable Class Type: Java.lang.Double

Calculation Type: Sum

Reset Type: Group

Reset Group: LOCATION_ID

Increment Type: None

Variable Expression: `new Double($F{QUANTITY_SENT}.doubleValue() > 0.00 ? 1.0:0.0)`

**TEXT FIELD**

Text Field Expression Class: Java.lang.Double

Evaluation Time: Group

Evaluation Group: LOCATION_ID

Text Field Expression: $V{PART_COUNT}

**QUESTION**
How do I now switch this expression to return an integer??

Thanks for pointing me in the right direction.

Answer (score 1):

I figured it out:

**TEXT FIELD**

Text Field Expression Class: Java.lang.Integer

Evaluation Time: Report

Text Field Expression: `new Integer($V{PART_COUNT}.intValue())`

Found answer here:
http://community.jaspersoft.com/questions/525053/cannot-cast-int-integer